# Replace some string values in a pandas dataframe column whose values should be float

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe with lat long values, whose types should be float. However, for some rows, you can find things like -74.128815°, with the '°' character in the end of the string.

| id | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4.807 | -75.684 |
| 2 | 4.5405 | -75.6658 |
| 3 |  | -74.128815° |
| 4 | 5.35002 | -72.4002 |
| 5 | 4.6774° | -75.693 |

I want to keep all float values as they are but replace the values containing '°' (and then convert them to float), so that in the end I have this:

| id | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4.807 | -75.684 |
| 2 | 4.5405 | -75.6658 |
| 3 |  | -74.128815 |
| 4 | 5.35002 | -72.4002 |
| 5 | 4.6774 | -75.693 |

The DataFrame is named df. I have tried
`df[df['Lat'].str.contains('°')]`
which raises `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values error`

Also, I've also tried `df['Lat'] = np.where(df['Lat'].str.contains('°'), df['Lat'][:-1], df['Lat'])` which raises `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together`

Answer (score 1):

You can `replace` the invalid character with an empty string, and then just use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
degree_sign = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}' # or degree_sign = "°"
df[['lat', 'long']].replace(degree_sign, '', regex=True)\
                   .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm embarassed that didn't cross my mind haha

Answer (score 1):

Using `regex` replace the last non-digit character(s) ('\D+')in the columns, then convert to float:

```
df[['Lat', 'Long']].replace('\\D+$', '', regex = True).astype(float)

       Lat       Long
0  4.80700 -75.684000
1  4.54050 -75.665800
2      NaN -74.128815
3  5.35002 -72.400200
4  4.67740 -75.693000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a string replace, then change the column type, for example

```
df['Lat'] = df['Lat'].astype('str').str.replace('°', '', regex=True).astype('float')
df['Long'] = df['Long'].astype('str').str.replace('°', '', regex=True).astype('float')
```